# javascript methods to check for dirty and show prompt on leave and a timeout method to show a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wrote two methods, one in javascript and other in an MVC razor application with C# as the code in the controller.

1. To check if any form is dirty and prompt if I exit the browser so that I can remain and save my form.
2. If the form is left idle then I bring up a jquery dialog and make the user choose to save or leave without saving.

I want to reference this script on every form in my application. I am trying to make it self contained so that I only need to include it on every form, without writing code on the form.

I am having problems with item 2 and the dialogue does not display. I am trying to append the `DIV` to the Jquery dialog. The reason I displayed item 1 is to show you that I have put these two together in the same fine. Even item 1 may need some tweaking as it works sometimes (prompt that you are leaving the site since it finds the form dirty and sometimes it does not). But my focus at this point is on item 2.

I would appreciate your help on item 2 (resetTimeout) at the moment. Thanks in advance.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

    $.fn.areYouSure = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend(
              {
                  'message': 'You are leaving the HRR application. Remain on this page and select "Next" to avoid loosing your changes.',
                  'dirtyClass': 'dirty',
                  'change': null,
                  'silent': false,
                  'fieldSelector': "select,textarea,input[type='text'],input[type='password'],input[type='checkbox'],input[type='radio'],input[type='hidden']"
              }, options);

        var getValue = function ($field) {
            if ($field.hasClass('ays-ignore')
                || $field.hasClass('aysIgnore')
                || $field.attr('data-ays-ignore')
                || $field.attr('name') === undefined) {
                return null;
            }

            if ($field.is(':disabled')) {
                return 'ays-disabled';
            }

            var val;
            var type = $field.attr('type');
            if ($field.is('select')) {
                type = 'select';
            }

            switch (type) {
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    val = $field.is(':checked');
                    break;
                case 'select':
                    val = '';
                    $field.children('option').each(function (o) {
                        var $option = $(this);
                        if ($option.is(':selected')) {
                            val += $option.val();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    val = $field.val();
            }

            return val;
        };

        var storeOrigValue = function () {
            var $field = $(this);
            $field.data('ays-orig', getValue($field));
        };

        var checkForm = function (evt) {
            var isFieldDirty = function ($field) {
                return (getValue($field) != $field.data('ays-orig'));
            };

            var isDirty = false;
            var $form = $(this).parents('form');

            // Test on the target first as it's the most likely to be dirty.
            if (isFieldDirty($(evt.target))) {
                isDirty = true;
            }

            if (!isDirty) {
                $form.find(settings.fieldSelector).each(function () {
                    $field = $(this);
                    if (isFieldDirty($field)) {
                        isDirty = true;
                        return false; // break
                    }
                });
            }

            markDirty($form, isDirty);
        };

        var markDirty = function ($form, isDirty) {
            var changed = isDirty != $form.hasClass(settings.dirtyClass);
            $form.toggleClass(settings.dirtyClass, isDirty);

            // Fire change event if required
            if (changed) {
                if (settings.change) settings.change.call($form, $form);

                if (isDirty) $form.trigger('dirty.areYouSure', [$form]);
                if (!isDirty) $form.trigger('clean.areYouSure', [$form]);
                $form.trigger('change.areYouSure', [$form]);
            }
        };

        var rescan = function () {
            var $form = $(this);
            var newFields = $form.find(settings.fieldSelector).not("[ays-orig]");
            $(newFields).each(storeOrigValue);
            $(newFields).bind('change keyup', checkForm);
        };


        if (!settings.silent) {
            $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
                $dirtyForms = $("form").filter('.' + settings.dirtyClass);
                //if ($dirtyForms.length > 0) {
                return settings.message;
                //}
            });
        }

        return this.each(function (elem) {
            if (!$(this).is('form')) {
                return;
            }
            var $form = $(this);

            $form.submit(function () {
                $form.removeClass(settings.dirtyClass);
            });
            $form.bind('reset', function () { markDirty($form, false); });
            // Add a custom event to support dynamic addition of new fields
            $form.bind('rescan.areYouSure', rescan);

            var fields = $form.find(settings.fieldSelector);
            $(fields).each(storeOrigValue);
            $(fields).bind('change keyup', checkForm);

        });
    };

    $('form').areYouSure();
    //debugger;
    resetTimeout = function () {
        var timeoutID;

      
        //resetTimeout1();

        //resetTimeout1 = function () {
          //  alert("resetTimeout1");
        //if (timeoutID) clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        //timeoutID = setTimeout(ShowTimeoutWarning, 5000);
        //alert(timeoutId);
        //}

        ShowTimeoutWarning = function () {
            //$("#Dialog").dialog('open');
            //var newDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
            //newDiv.html('hello there');
            alert("timeoutwarning");
            var html = '';
          
            html = '<p>Emails cannot be uploaded. Invoices received by email from your contractor need to be saved as a separate document and uploaded.</p>';

            
            $('<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">You will lose the changes in your application. Do you want to save it?</div>').appendTo('body');

           //.html(html)
           $("#dialog").dialog({
               buttons: [
                   //{
                   //    text: "Yes",
                   //    click: function () {
                   //        ShowTimeoutWarning();
                   //        $(this).dialog("close");
                   //    }
                   //},
                   {
                       text: "Yes",
                       click: function () {
                           //ShowTimeoutWarning();
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                       }
                   },
                   {
                       text: "Cancel",
                       click: function () {
                           //ShowTimeoutWarning();
                           $(this).dialog("close");
                       }
                   }
               ],
               height: 400,
               width: 400,
               maxHeight: 720,
               maxWidth: 720,
               title: "Hero"
           });

            return false;
        }

        if (timeoutID) clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = setTimeout(ShowTimeoutWarning, 5000);

        document.onkeyup = resetTimeout;
        document.onkeydown = resetTimeout;
        document.onclick = resetTimeout;

        
    }

    resetTimeout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to test without having code to look at.  The first thing I notice is that you need to define a 'div' for the dialog so that you will have something to show when the dialog is called to be displayed.

```
<body> 
   <div id="dlgWarning" title="Timeout warning" style="display:none">
      <p>You will lose the changes in your application. Do you want to save it?</p>
   </div> 
</body>
```

Once that is done you will need to have your timeout function show the dialog

```
$('dlgWarning').show();
```

Reference this https://jqueryui.com/dialog/